# Setting the host time from a docker container gives permission error even with CAP_SYS_TIME

Tags: permissions, time, docker, selinux

I'm trying to test `docker` capabilities usage. So, for this I'm trying to run a container with the `--cap-add=SYS_TIME` capability, which should allow a process to set the system time, however this is the output I receive:

```
$ sudo docker run --cap-add=SYS_TIME --rm -it ubuntu bash
root@617c9eb44965:/# date -s '+2 hours'
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Tue Mar  6 10:17:46 UTC 2018
root@617c9eb44965:/#
```

If I replace `--cap-add` with `--cap-drop` nothing changes in the output:

```
$ sudo docker run --cap-drop=SYS_TIME --rm -it ubuntu bash
root@46dbb20ad793:/# date -s '+2 hours'
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Tue Mar  6 10:19:03 UTC 2018
```

It puzzles me that the `date` command still outputs the date increased by 2 hours, instead of simply dying with an error (the exit code is `1`).

The only thing that I can think of is that seccomp/selinux are coming into play, but I have no idea how to check for that.

Can somebody explain me how can I ensure what is causing the operation not permitted error even when the capability is explicitly set and how to fix that?

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ws77 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
```

<sub>Please, **do not mention  `--privileged`.** It's broken and I want to do it in the proper way using capabilities/seccomp/selinux etc.</sub>

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8460#issuecomment-258684710, https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25622?

Comment: @muru AFAIK I don't use the userns feature., so those links are not relevant. There is no `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file in my computer and `ps aux | grep userns` only returns the grep command as output.